# Cannot update identity column SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to update the Identity column, and it does not exists in any relational table as of now.

If I run the SQL statement as shown:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Client..dt_Domain ON;

UPDATE Client..dt_Domain
SET DomainID = 1
WHERE DomainID = 2 AND ClientID = 3

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Client..dt_Domain OFF;
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Cannot update identity column 'DomainID'.

Comment: @JamesZ I saw that solution before posting this question, and that is not working for me.

Comment: What is not working specifically about that answer? Because it's correct (and the only real way to do it). If there's nothing in your table where DomainID = 1 then insert all of the same values with a DomainID of 1 and delete where DomainID = 2...

Comment: @ZLK I get the same error if I try to insert with indentity as on `Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 6# # Cannot update identity column 'DomainID'.`

Comment: @ZLK To insert records and then delete it was the last solution, if nothing works :)

Comment: So you've tried something like `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Client..dt_Domain ON; INSERT Client..dt_Domain(a, b, c) SELECT 1, b, c FROM Client..dt_Domain WHERE a = 2; DELETE Client..dt_Domain WHERE a = 2;SET IDENTITY_INSERT Client..dt_Domain OFF;` and that produced the same error? Because I don't see how that's possible, given you're not updating anything...

Comment: I don't know what prb that had, so I just did dummy entries and reached till a point which suffice my DomainID requirement. Thanks for your time @ZLK

Comment: You can **INSERT** explicit values into an identity column with the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT... ON` help - but you can **NEVER UPDATE** an existing value in an identity column. No mechanism, no hack, no "workaround" - it just cannot be done.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to `Update` the Identity column.

But instead you can Delete the old record & Insert the same record with your desired Identity number by setting `IDENTITY_INSERT` ON

Comment: I tried with Insert, but it also ended up with same message. Hence, I added the record and then thought of updating it. But now I am stuck again.

Comment: Is your Insert violating any constraints like Unique or Primary Key? @AaBa

Comment: DomainID is the PK and ClientID is the FK, rest there are no keys in that table.

Comment: @AaBa There may be a chance of having already a record with `DomainID = 1`

Comment: Nope, there were no rows with ID 1. Anyways, I took a donkey approach and moving ahead as I need to fix another 8 tables likes this. Phew! Thanks for your time @Shakeer